# Eliminar espacios en blanco de diferentes "div"

Tags: css, scss, next.js, uikit-3

tengo éste problema, necesito eliminar las secciones en blanco que me quedan en los espacios de las imagenes. Sabrán de alguna propiedad con css para eliminarlas? [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Sin tu código no puedo ayudarte mucho que digamos, pero podrías usar `display: inline-block;` en `css`

Comment: Deberías compartir tu codigo HTML y nos harás mucho mas facil ayudarte.

Comment: Necesitamos ver tu código para hacernos una idea y poder darte la mejor respuesta posible. Yo probaría a hacer un reset del CSS. Puedes encontrar ejemplos por internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues para eliminar los espacios no se me ocurre nada, pero como idea puedes ajustar la altura de las imágenes para que tengan todas la misma (ponles un height, aunque no siempre deja), o agruparlas por altura (pon en la misma fila las largas), o retocar las imágenes directamente.

Si haces lo primero, va a ser más fácil que le des la altura al div contenedor. Sin ver tu código no sé como lo tienes, pero mi consejo es que metas cada fila en un div y ya les pones a todas la misma clase a la que le das la altura.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).